# Session variable is not clearing in Laravel using Route Redirect with

Tags: session, laravel-5.1

I'm using Laravel 5.1 and Zizaco/Entrust for roles & permissions. Here i'v an  issue while clearing the session variable. As per my understanding **with()** method – its purpose is to add an error message or some input data only for that particular redirect and only for one page. In my case it is redirecting properly to the dashboard but the session message is existing even after refreshing the page.

**Route**

```
<?php
  Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth'], function () 
  { 
        Route::get('dashboard', function () { 
          return view('dashboard');
        });
       Entrust::routeNeedsPermission('add_item', 'Create_Item', Redirect::to('dashboard/')->with('message', 'You Dont have peremissions..'), false );
       Route::get('add_item', 'ItemController@create');
  });
```

**View**

```
@if(Session::has('message')) 
  <p class="alert {{ Session::get('alert-class', 'alert-info') }}">{{     Session::get('message') }}</p>
  {{Session::forget('message')}}
@endif
```

I tried dumping the session by refreshing the page. I have no idea why 'message' is still existing in the session data. Help me to figure out this issue

Answer (score 0):

Data stored in the session using with() (flash data) will be only available on the next Http request and then will be deleted. Meaning you don't even have to add `{{Session::forget('message')}}` to your code.

Entrust package uses `Route::filter` (in `routeNeedsPermission` and other functions) which is deprecated as of `Laravel 5.1`.

May be your redirect is not processed the way it is meant to be.

Comment: I agree with the first one ie flash data. Second one is interesting. still wondering to fix it,

Comment: What happens when you call Redirect::to('dashboard/')->with('message', 'You Dont have peremissions..'); not within the entrust function call but outside it?

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. As of now route is getting redirect to dashboard and it is displaying the message after that when ever i m again in the dashboard the same message is appearing.

Comment: and what is your session driver?

Comment: by the way you should run   php artisan route:clear  if you have optimized them

Comment: How did you fix this @siva? I'm having the exact same issue, with Entrust and 5.1